# Following a tutorial using Django/Python: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pages'

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and am trying to create a very simple app off of a tutorial I found online.

Working on a mac
Django Version 2.0.7
Python 3.7.0

My file structure:

```
helloworld
......venv
..........(other files)
......helloworld_project
..........(other files)
......manage.py
......pages
.........._ pycache _
..............otherfiles
..........admin.py
..........apps.py
..........migrations
..............(other files)
..........models.py
..........tests.py
..........urls.py
..........views.py
```

The problem: when I run my urls.py file, I get the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "/Users/Bethany/Desktop/helloworld/pages/urls.py",         
line 3, in <module>
    from pages import views
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pages'
My urls.py file:

# pages/urls.py
from django.urls import path
from pages import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.homePageView, name='home')
]
```

I've tried replacing "from pages import views" with "from . import views" and get the same message.

I've looked through a few  similar questions on stack overflow, but haven't had success with finding a solution to fix my issue. does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

If needed, this is the tutorial I'm following: https://djangoforbeginners.com/hello-world/

Comment: is pages in your INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py?

Comment: yes and there is a red line under pages and views

Comment: Your import is wrong

Answer (score 0):

You are not importing `views` from page actually, you want to import the HomePageView from your views.

Change your code to this:

```
 # pages/urls.py
from django.urls import path
from .views import homePageView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.homePageView, name='home')
]
```

Comment: Did your add your page URL to the main urls.py ?

Comment: from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from pages.views import home_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('', home_view, name='home'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

This is what my urls.py looks like

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `__init__.py` file is present in pages app ? If this file is not present in the pages folder, then any file will not be considered as a module.

Comment: Its all there, is pycache  necessary?

Comment: Wait, are you trying to run urls.py file itself ? You are supposed to run manage.py runserver command, and not urls.py python file.

Comment: It's fixed, the problem was that it was supposed to be src.pages.views.